# where to write custom blade if statements in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

According to [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#custom-if-statements), we should write *Custom If Statements*  in `boot()` method in `AppServiceProvider`, but what if they're too many?

I'd like to move them somewhere else, but I don't know what is the best practice.
Where should we write *Custom If Statements* if they're too many?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it in a custom service provider for that task

```
php artisan make:provider BladeDirectivesServiceProvider
```

Add that Service Provider to the array in `config/app.php`

```
'providers' => [
    ...
    App\Providers\BladeDirectivesServiceProvider::class
]
```

And register the blade directives in the `boot` method of the new Service Provider.